# How to avoid MVC resetting ExceptionContext.Result?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code to handle exceptions in my MVC controllers:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{    
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                    {
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                        Data = new { Error = true, Msj = filterContext.Exception.Message }
                    };
                }
    }
```

In the front-end I am using angularjs ($http) to execute the requests.

If I set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled` to true, $http will execute the successCallback function but if I don't set it, .Net will reset the `filterContext.Result` to the tipycal yellow page.

I want to manage the error with the errorCallback function($http) but avoid .Net resetting the `Data` property of the JsonResult

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it?

Any help will be appreciated =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular `$http` service does not send the `X-Requested-With` headers by [default](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d). You need to explicitly enable it.

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

**EDIT :** As per the comment

> The problem is that .Net replaces the 'Data' property

Because your are missing 2 things in your `OnException` method.

1. You need to set the `ExceptionHandled` property to `true` so that the framework will not do the normal exception handling procedure and return the default yellow screen of death page.
2. You need to specify the Response status code as 5xx ( Error response). The client library will determine whether to execute the success callback or error callback based on the status code on the response coming back.

The below code should totally work.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
    {
         filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
         {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { Error = true, Msj = filterContext.Exception.Message   }
         };
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
         filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have done it. The problem is that .Net replaces the 'Data' property